# sql select performance (Microsoft)

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a very big table with many rows (50 million) and more than 500 columns. Its indexes are period and client. I need to keep for a period the client and another column (not an index). It takes too much time. So I'm trying to understand why:

If I do:

```
select count(*)
from table
where cd_periodo=201602
```

It takes less than 1 sec and returns the number 2 million.

If I select into a temp table the period it also takes no time (2 secs)

```
select cd_periodo
into #table
from table
where cd_periodo=201602
```

But if I select another column that it's not part of an index it takes more than 3 minutes.

```
select not_index_column
into #table
from table
where cd_periodo=201602
```

Why is this happening? I'm not doing any filter on the column.

Comment: Please include (minimized) DDL for table and indexes. Have you inspected the query plans?

Comment: A table with more than 500 columns?? That sounds like a scary design. Without a lot more details here were are guessing at best.

Answer (score 2):

When you select an indexed column, the reader doesn't have to process and go into the entire table and read the entire row. The index helps the reader to select the value without having to actually get the row.

When you select a nonindexed column, the opposite of what I said happens, and the reader have to read the whole table in order to get the value from this column.

Comment: thanks, but why the whole table? I thought it looked for the column name first and then for the values.